# How to dispatch an action and invoke component method in redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a form component and a button in   different component. I am trying to get values of form on click of the button.

In flux I used to attach events in components but how can we achieve in redux.

Comment: Have you tried redux-form? http://redux-form.com/5.2.3/#/?_k=hcc0yj

Comment: Using `props.dispatch` which appears on components that are connected to the store with `connect`

Comment: submit button will not be part of the same form and in another component I need all values of that form. If the components has parent- child relationship then I can get the values using 'ref'. But in my case both are independent components.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Redux `Provider`sits at the "top-level" of your React application, the form can dispatch actions to save its current values to the state of the store.

This state can then be passed to the button component by wrapping it with the `connect` function.